# Is there any best numerical iteration methods than perform faster than reduced row echelon method?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

In order to find the best low-rank approximation, are there any numerical methods perform faster than using a reduced row echelon form to find the rank of a matrix?